# How I do I host a simple html file through wordpress? (see details)

Tags: ftp

I want to host a webpage on my main directory so that my url reads:

```
www.example.com/sample.html
```

I know I can use FTP service but is there any plugin I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: If it's a static file and it doesn't need to know anything about wordpress... just put the file in the root directory.

Comment: Yes, I can simply do that. But I only had access to WordPress admin dashboard. I stated that in the question that I need to use a plugin. I sorted this out however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin "File Manager" - https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-manager/, you will need to have the requirements below:

PHP 5.2+
Firefox 12+
Google Chrome / Chromium 19+
Internet Explorer 9+
Opera 12+
Safari 6
Mogrify Utility (Optional)
GD / Imagic (Optional)